# C# interface cannot be instantiated so why can I use IEnumerable without specifying concrete type

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that interfaces cannot be instantiated but that an instance of an object that implements the interface can be created.

But in this example, I am working with an interface variable and it's never instantiated to an object of a class.

```
public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people = AMethod<IEnumerable<Person>>();
    return people;
}

var people = MyClass.GetPeople();
// ... operations on the people variable
```

So at no point am I referring to an array or a list or another type that implements IEnumerable. When I debug this code the debugger shows that the people variable is of type IEnumerable< Person  >. But how could it be if interfaces are not "the real thing" but only a contract? Like in memory is this an array, a list, something else? I am following a course on interfaces but I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: How is `AMethod` implemented?

Comment: "So at no point am I referring to an array or a list or another type that implements IEnumerable." - ah? Did you read your code? "IEnumerable<Person> people = AMethod<IEnumerable<Person>>();" - here is your reference.

Comment: I bet `AMethod` creates some instance that implements the interface.

Comment: AMethod is actually this: public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)

Comment: @TomTom `AMethod` returns an interface, so the code above does not show a class being  instantiated.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer `DeserializeObject` is creating a concrete type, then. You can look at the result of `people.GetType()` to see the actual concrete type implementing `IEnumerable<Person>`

Comment: Yes, but that method is not shown. That it reutrns an interface does not mean that it acutally internally implements it. And this is the whole crux here. It likely does NOT return "an interface" but "an instance of a class/struct that can be cast to the interface".

Comment: @TomTom There's no _likely_ about it; it _must_ return an instance, but `AMethod` returns an interface just like `GetPeople`. This proves nothing to the OP who is clearly confused.

Comment: @canton7 you're right, GetType() showed that AMethod actually returns a list. Makes sense now thanks

Comment: well, only because the **reference** which is returned by a member is of an interface-type does not mean that the underlying **object** is of that type. Actually that object just belongs to a class that implements that interface. So what you get is more or less a view on a concrete object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AMethod<IEnumerable<Person>>()
```

This is calling a method that looks something like this:

```
public  T AMethod <T> {
      // Do something to create an instance of T
}
```

`IEnumerable<Person>` is what you're passing to the `<T>` of the `AMethod` signature. It's a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

The result of that is that something concrete (like `Person[]`, `List<Person>` etc) is being created to fit the interface `IEnumerable<Person>`. But it's created by `AMethod`, not any of the code you've posted.

If you're curious about exactly what type people actually is, and can't just look at `AMethod`, calling `Type concreteType = people.GetType();` will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The useful thing with an abstraction like `IEnumerable<T>` is that is implemented by many classes.

For instance:

a `List<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`.

An `ImmutableArray<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`.

An array `T[]` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>` (though it's a bit of compiler magic, see comments).

Saying that a method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` just mean *this method will return something that implements `IEnumerable`, you don't need to care which one, but you can rely on the fact that the interface is implemented and thus use `foreach` and linq methods on it*.

If all you need is to be able to *enumerate* something with `foreach`, or apply linq methods, you can hide the actual implementation (array or list or whatever) and work with the `IEnumerable` instead.

On a general note, why do you want to use an abstraction? Here is a short start answer.

Imagine you rely on a specific implementation, like `List<T>`, and later you pass this to other functions as `List<T>` parameters etc... And your code grows like this.

One day you realize that `List<T>` is not a good choice for some reason (for performance, or because you now use another library that returns some other kind of class).

Now you need to untangle everything that was relying on this `List` assumption.

Comment: "An T[] is an IEnumerable<T>". Actually an array does not implement that interface, because generics were introduced far later than arrays. However we get some compiler-magic that converts an array into something that is iterable.